# no_parents/no_results Using playa entry results based on a url segment, want to display no results

Tags: templates, playa, conditionals, no-results

I have a list that builds based on the URL segment. Sometimes there no entries for the segment and need to display "no results". I have tried several varations on this and nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions are greatly appriciated, thanks for looking.

I have tried to take this another direction and am tying to use {if no_parents} … {/if} variable.

However written like this it only shows up when there are results not when there is no results.
Here is what my code looks like now

```
{exp:channel:entries 
   channel="my_child_channel"
   orderby="data_contact_last_name"
   sort="asc" 
   limit="3"
   }

     {exp:playa:parents 
     channel="mychannel" 
     field="my_field"
     var_prefix="my_var"
     }


        {if no_parents} no parent content {/if} 

        <!-- label -->  
        {if count == '1'} 
         <h4 class="f400m"><strong>{child:title}</strong></h4>  <!-- The title-->
        {/if}

            <h4><a href="{my_var:url_title}">{my_var:title}</a></h4>

   {/exp:playa:parents}
```

Earlier I tried this and what Jason suggested i also could not get to work.

```
{exp:channel:entries 
   channel="my_channel" 
   limit="3"
   }

   {exp:playa:parents 
      channel="my_parent_channel" 
      field="field_choice" 
      require_entry="yes"}

{if no_results}  <p>There are no entries available.</p>  {/if}

     {if count == '1'} 
         <h4>{child:title}</h4>
      {/if}

       <h4><a href="{url_title}">{title}</a></h4>

 {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Did you try my variation below?

Comment: Yes I did and it does not display the message and breaks my {if count == '1'}<h4><a href="{url_title}">{title}</a></h4>{/if}. Now I needed add the var_prefix anyway and have been busy trying to get the original child to work for that purpose. It was recommended I use {if no_parents} by Anris but I can't get that to work either.

Comment: You'll have to prefix the subsequent tags as well… `{if my_var:count =='1'}` Code updated below.

Comment: Does not work, then no title label shows up at all. Tried a couple of variations. There has to be some way to get this work. Thanks for looking, anything else you might have is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `if no_results` is actually referencing the outer `exp:channel:entries` tag - basically an EE parse order issue.

To test inside playa, you need to use the `var_prefix` parameter... as in:

```
{exp:playa:parents var_prefix="my_var"}
{if my_var:no_results}
    //no results behaviour here
{/if}
{if my_var:count == '1'} 
     <h4 class="f400m"><strong>{child:title}</strong></h4>  <!-- The Str Discipline title-->
{/if}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

The docs: https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/parents.html

Comment: Or as a simplier solution, just make sure you also have {if no_results}no entry to display {/if} for channel entries tag.